# Copiar un archivo de un servidor a otro a través de rutas remotas - PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

tardes o noches, este es mi primer post.

Actualmente me encuentro en un dilema con php, necesito pasar un archivo de un servidor a otro a través de rutas remotas en windows, primeramente estoy intentado crear un directorio para asegurarme que antes de hacer el copiado exista el directorio a través de la función mkdir pasando por parámetro la ruta y los permisos, después he usado la instrucción COPY en donde de primer parámetro le envío la ruta de donde encuentra el archivo y como segundo parámetro la ruta a donde se enviará de la siguiente manera:

Crear directorio:

```
mkdir($destino, 0777, true);
```

Copiado de archivo:

```
copy($origen.$archivo, $destino.$archivo)
```

Pero me arrojan los siguientes errores:

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory

copy("ruta destino") [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Nota: Cabe resaltar que la ruta destino es una ruta remota en windows con la sintáxis:
\IP\directorio

PD: Una disculpa por no poder poner el código tal cual, no me es permitido debido a la empresa en la que laboro.